# Get result from BaseQuery object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLalchemy and have entered data into the database:

```
class Directions(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    key = db.Column(db.String(16), index=True, unique=False)
```

Now, I'm trying to search for a given key:

```
Directions.query.filter(Directions.key=={some string})
```

But I get:

```
<flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object at 0x103df57b8>
```

How do I uncover the actual result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using this:

```
direction = Directions.query.filter_by(key == <some string>).first()
print(direction)
```

Answer (score 8):

The [`filter`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) method return a `BaseQuery` object which you can chain multiple filters on it. You use `first` or `all` to get the results of current query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open up a session and use the query method of the session object. For example:

```
engine = create_engine(<db url>)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

with Session() as sess:
    sess.query(Directions).filter(Direction.key=={some string})
```

That code leading up to the `Session` call is described in the [Session Documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#getting-a-session) and might change for your application. You can read more about query objects in the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html) as well.